# scoring in grid search is test scoring or test scoring?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using grid search to find right parameters.

Following is my code.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
gbm = GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=2)

parameters = {"loss" : ("deviance", "exponential"), \
              "learning_rate":[0.1, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05], \
              "n_estimators":[100, 500, 1000, 5000],\
             "max_depth":[1,3,5],\
             "subsample":[0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 1],\
             "max_features":("sqrt", "log2", 1.0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8)}

from sklearn import grid_search
gs = grid_search.GridSearchCV(gbm, parameters, scoring="log_loss", n_jobs=-1,cv=3, verbose=5)
gs.fit(train, y)
```

my question here is, how does scoring(here log_loss) is calcuated ? it is log_loss of data which, are used in building model or data, which are left out during each CV and then average of scoring ?

Comment: Read the docs: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#log-loss

Comment: I know how they calculate log_loss. I want to know what they using (a. train logloss, b. test logloss or c. validation logloss) when they report during grid search

Comment: The "CV" (cross-validation) in the name speaks for itself. The error is estimated on "left-out" data via cross-validation.

Comment: Indeed, estimated on the left-out data and then averaged.